# Where in Snow White does it explain how the Queen knows Snow white?

Tags: snow-white

In the 1937 film *Snow White*, the Queen asks the Magic Mirror "who is the fairest of them all":

> **Queen**: Slave in the magic mirror, come from the farthest space, through wind and darkness I summon thee. Speak! Let me see thy face.
>
> **Magic Mirror**: What wouldst thou know, my Queen?
>
> **Queen**: Magic mirror on the wall, who is the fairest one of all?
>
> **Magic Mirror**: Famed is thy beauty, Majesty. But hold, a lovely maid I see. Rags cannot hide her gentle grace. Alas, she is more fair than thee.
>
> **Queen**: Alas for her! Reveal her name.
>
> **Magic Mirror**: Lips red as the rose. Hair black as ebony. Skin white as snow.
>
> **Queen**: Snow White!

Despite demanding a name, the mirror remains cryptic, giving only more description. However, the Queen is still able to determine who it is.

Having recently re-watched the film, I don't see where the Queen would have encountered Snow White well enough to know her name. The first time we see her she is a maid in a castle, but no link is made that this is the Queen's castle or otherwise.

In the film, how does the Queen make this logical leap?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is explained in the opening of the film where a book opens up, setting the scene, and explains that Snow White lives with her Stepmother who forces her to work as a scullery maid.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well spotted. Seems obvious now, but I had assumed the Book was the continuation of the opening credits! Not sure what film made me think that.